# Bootstrap 4 Modal Background

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

does anybody know how to change the modal background? (The card thing, not the outside of the modal.)

I don't want to change the background outside of the modal (`just like in this example https://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/oqmPmY`), I want to change the modal itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the Bootstrap css within your "local" css by changing the following classes:

- .modal-content (the container div for the items below)
- .modal-body
- .modal-header
- .modal-footer

So to change just the body of the modal dialog you could use:

```
.modal-body {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

By default, Bootstrap applies a background style only to `.modal-content` which is then inherited by `.modal-body`, `.modal-header`, `.modal-footer`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked. But what if I had more than one modal on my website? Should I use id's?

Comment: Yup. Id's will work. The example shown in the BS docs does that on the outer-most container. Only use that id. Don't give .modal-body, .modal-content, etc. there own id's. You can reference the `.modal-body` using the outer-most div's id and the .modal-body class. `#outer-most-div .modal-body` for example.